# Use shared Preference values in Repository or ViewModel of Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-architecture-components

I am using `ArchitectureComponents` in my application.I am making `API` request from `ViewModel` and setting data to `RecyclerView` using ViewModel in ActivityMain.For making a Api call I need a `Token` which is saved in `SharedPreference`.I need to get that token and add it in Headers while making request.Where and how to get the SharedPreference value. It should be get in ViewModel or Repository.
This is code for my `ViewModel`

```
public class FoodieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   FoodieRepository repository;
   MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Foodie>> foodieList;
    public FoodieViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository=new FoodieRepository(application);
    }

     LiveData<ArrayList<Foodie>> getAllFoodie(){
        if(foodieList==null){
            foodieList=new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Foodie>>();
            loadFoodies();
        }
        return foodieList;
    }
    public void loadFoodies(){
        String url="somethimg.com";
        JsonArrayRequest request =new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                ArrayList<Foodie> list=new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Foodie foodie=new Foodie();
                        String name=obj.getString("firstname");
                        foodie.setName(name);
                        list.add(foodie);
                    }

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                foodieList.setValue(list);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String auth = "JWT " + "sometoken";
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

How to get the Token if it is stored in `SharedPreference` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class FoodieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
........
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =getApplication().getSharedPreferences("preference_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...........

//wherever u want to get token
String token = sharedpreferences.getString("token", "")

}
```

Comment: You can create a separate repository for the shared preferences. Then add that in your view model using custom factory. Check this https://arkapp.medium.com/how-to-use-shared-preferences-the-easy-and-fastest-way-98ce2013bf51

Comment: That article uses repository in Activity/Fragment. From my understanding, all business logic, including the "is the value x or y" questions that are dependant on variable value  from SharedPreferences, is done in ViewModels, not in Activities/Fragments.
Going through bunch of posts and seems like the only correct way to use shared preference from repository, is to get application context from AndroidViewModel (as mentioned above) and then manually instantiating "MyAppDataRepository" with that application context right in the viewmodel.

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/sharedviewmodel-in-kotlin-ec9b09b41a78

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using AndroidViewModel?  I've heard bad things about using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sharedPreference object in repository class in its constructor. Assuming that you have made a repository class (Singleton).

```
  //This class should be a singleton.
  public class YourRepositoryClass{
    //Initialize your token in your repository class's constructor
     String token=null;
    private YourRepositoryClass(Application application)
   {
     //your codes 

   //get your token in the repository and use whenever any viewmodel triggers repository to make a request
   // No need for getting token each time for different view models in case you are using multiple activities or fragments.


   SharedPreferences mPref=application.getSharedPreferences("preference_key",MODE_PRIVATE);
   token=mPref.getString("token",null);


        }

    // your other data request functions can be put here so that different view models can get data through this repository. Here use this token for making api requests.

  }
```

You don't have to call SharedPreferences again and again for each and every view model and every view model can easily ask for specific data using repository class.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass Context to the ViewModel such as:

```
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
   viewModel.setContext(new MutableLiveData<>(this));
```

Then use it to get any resources of activity.

In ViewModel:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getValue().getSharedPreferences("myPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("token", token);
        editor.apply();
```

Comment: passing context is not a good idea cause context has a different lifecycle then the viewModel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2BtE1P6MPE&t=225s